# VBA/Excel UserForm does not support Implements?

Tags: excel, vba

if i try the following Code i get the **Runtime Error 459** 
and for the love of god i can't figre out if this is a bug or if UserForms simple and for unknown reasons don't implement that feature?!

Class named "ViewInterface"

```
Option Explicit
Public Event ButtonPressed(ButtonID As ButtonID, Selected As Long)
…
Public Sub ClearList()
End Sub
…
```

in UserForm named frmMain

```
Option Explicit
Implements ViewInterface
…
```

in another class (name irrelevant)

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents view As ViewInterface
…
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set view = New frmMain '<-- this throws the temper tantrum
End Sub
```

any suggestions?
any clarifications?
or do i have to build a workaround for this

Comment: Does `frmMain` have an `Initialize` handler? Forms can absolutely implement interfaces, but interfaces cannot expose events.. Not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: ok that seems correct.(the Event thingy was bullshit on my side, i really don't know why i've done this) what i had tried was to use multiple versions of forms, different design, same functionality to Show my cusomer.
!!thank you without the Events it works.